# How can I check the cron jobs running on my site?

Tags: magento-1, cron

How can I check the cron jobs running on my site on terminal?

Magento ver. 1.6.2.0

Answer (score 2, accepted):

if you are using Linux server

```
pgrep cron
```

or

```
/etc/init.d/crond status
```

It will show the cron id. if cron id will show cron is running fine. else cron is dead are not running.

otherwise please install aoe scheduler. it will show the heartbeat of cron running.

Hope it will helpful for you.

Answer (score 0):

Log into your server via your ssh client.

Once logged in as the root user, use the following command to check the log for the cron script. The command will use the following format: grep "script.php" /path/file.ext. For instance, the code below is looking for the script cronscript.php in the cron.log file, which is in the /var/log folder.

Follow this blog, it contains more information

https://www.inmotionhosting.com/support/website/cron-jobs/did-cron-job-run

Answer (score 0):

[AOE Scheduler](https://github.com/AOEpeople/Aoe_Scheduler) is an awesome FREE extension to view all cron jobs running in Magento. You can view settings per cron job and see a timeline of all jobs run and if there were any errors. This has been a life-saver for many years.